# Equivalent Perl pack ("H*") in Java with non-hexadecimal characters

Tags: java, perl, hex, byte, pack

I'm trying to rewrite Perl script to Java. There is a line in this script with pack function:

```
my $key = '0rdR-0PrdK';
$key = pack("H*", $key);
```

The method i use in java is:

```
private static byte[] hexToBytes(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                + Character.digit(s.charAt(i + 1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}
```

it works correctly on hex strings, but it doesnt on non-hex strings

on the left bytes received in java, on the right from perl  **'0rdR-0PrdK'**

```
-1      11
-49     -37
-16     -48
-17     -101
-49     -44
```

Have any of you had such a problem? How to solve it?

Comment: You can see for yourself that Java returns -1 for invalid hex digits, whereas perl returns a modulo-16 value of {digit - '0'} (e.g. 'F' = 15, 'G' = 0, 'H' = 1, 'I' = 2...) so using that knowledge you can work it out yourself. However, it's intriguing why you would ever want to use perl's pack function on invalid inputs in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

`pack("H*", '0rdR-0PrdK')` produces garbage.

```
$ perl -M5.014 -e'
   my $encoded = pack "H*", $ARGV[0];
   my $decoded = unpack "H*", $encoded;
   say $decoded;
   say $decoded eq $ARGV[0] ? "ok" : "ERROR";
' 0rdR-0PrdK
0bdbd09bd4
ERROR
```

It's impossible to get `0rdR-0PrdK` from the the output of `pack("H*", 0rdR-0PrdK")`.

Someone meant to use `unpack "H*"` but accidentally used `pack "H*"`.

```
# bytes -> hex
$ perl -M5.014 -e'say unpack "H*", $ARGV[0]' 0rdR-0PrdK
307264522d305072644b

# hex -> bytes
$ perl -M5.014 -e'say pack "H*", $ARGV[0]' \
   "$( perl -M5.014 -e'say unpack "H*", $ARGV[0]' 0rdR-0PrdK )"
0rdR-0PrdK
```

You should fix that instead of trying to work around the bug.

---

The bytes you want can be obtained using the following:

```
$ perl -M5.014 -e'say for unpack "c*", pack "H*", $ARGV[0]' 0rdR-0PrdK
11
-37
-48
-101
-44
```

The following will provide a string you can pass to `hexToBytes` to obtain the same result:

```
$ perl -M5.014 -e'say for unpack "H*", pack "H*", $ARGV[0]' 0rdR-0PrdK
0bdbd09bd4
```

Answer (score 1):

> `pack("H*", '0rdR-0PrdK')` produces garbage.

Thats true, but this garbage were used as secret key in encryption algorithm. It was possible to decrypt when you used the same garbage.

I was really pressed on time so i did it this way:

- I found packed(H*...) value of every character in Perl
- encode them with Base64
- decode hardcoded values in Java

```
    private static final String[] possibleChars = {"0`", "`0", "0~", "~0", "0!", "!0", "0@", "@0", "0#", "#0", "0$", "$0", "0%", "%0", "0^", "^0",
                "0&", "&0", "0*", "*0", "0(", "(0", "0)", ")0", "0-", "-0", "0_", "_0", "0=", "=0", "0+", "+0", "0[", "[0", "0{", "{0",
                "0]", "]0", "0}", "}0", "0\\", "\\0", "0|", "|0", "0;", ";0", "0:", ":0", "0'", "'0", "0\"", "\"0", "0,", ",0", "0<",
                "<0", "0.", ".0", "0>", ">0", "0/", "/0", "0?", "?0", "0a", "a0", "0b", "b0", "0c", "c0", "0d", "d0", "0e", "e0", "0f",
                "f0", "0g", "g0", "0h", "h0", "0i", "i0", "0j", "j0", "0k", "k0", "0l", "l0", "0m", "m0", "0n", "n0", "0o", "o0", "0p",
                "p0", "0q", "q0", "0r", "r0", "0s", "s0", "0t", "t0", "0u", "u0", "0v", "v0", "0w", "w0", "0x", "x0", "0y", "y0", "0z",
                "z0", "00", "00", "01", "10", "02", "20", "03", "30", "04", "40", "05", "50", "06", "60", "07", "70", "08", "80", "09", "90"};
    private static final String[] base64codes = {"AA==", "AA==", "Dg==", "4A==", "AQ==", "EA==", "AA==", "AA==", "Aw==", "MA==", "BA==",
                "QA==", "BQ==", "UA==", "Dg==", "4A==", "Bg==", "YA==", "Cg==", "oA==", "CA==", "gA==", "CQ==", "kA==", "DQ==", "0A==",
                "Dw==", "8A==", "DQ==", "0A==", "Cw==", "sA==", "Cw==", "sA==", "Cw==", "sA==", "DQ==", "0A==", "DQ==", "0A==", "DA==",
                "wA==", "DA==", "wA==", "Cw==", "sA==", "Cg==", "oA==", "Bw==", "cA==", "Ag==", "IA==", "DA==", "wA==", "DA==", "wA==",
                "Dg==", "4A==", "Dg==", "4A==", "Dw==", "8A==", "Dw==", "8A==", "Cg==", "oA==", "Cw==", "sA==", "DA==", "wA==", "DQ==",
                "0A==", "Dg==", "4A==", "Dw==", "8A==", "AA==", "AA==", "AQ==", "EA==", "Ag==", "IA==", "Aw==", "MA==", "BA==", "QA==",
                "BQ==", "UA==", "Bg==", "YA==", "Bw==", "cA==", "CA==", "gA==", "CQ==", "kA==", "Cg==", "oA==", "Cw==", "sA==", "DA==",
                "wA==", "DQ==", "0A==", "Dg==", "4A==", "Dw==", "8A==", "AA==", "AA==", "AQ==", "EA==", "Ag==", "IA==", "Aw==", "MA==",
                "AA==", "AA==", "AQ==", "EA==", "Ag==", "IA==", "Aw==", "MA==", "BA==", "QA==", "BQ==", "UA==", "Bg==", "YA==", "Bw==",
                "cA==", "CA==", "gA==", "CQ==", "kA=="};

    private static void initializeHashMap() {
            for (int i = 0; i < possibleChars.length; i++) {
                hashMap.put(possibleChars[i], base64codes[i]);
            }
    }
    
    public static byte[] h16pack(String s) {
            String str = s.toLowerCase();
            int len = s.length();
            byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
                data[i / 2] = (byte) (Base64.decode(hashMap.get(str.charAt(i) + "0"))[0]
                        + Base64.decode(hashMap.get("0" + str.charAt(i + 1)))[0]);
            }
            return data;
    }
```

not elegant, but it works